# htaccess Rewrite Rule not working on certain pages

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

im having some difficulty with Rewrite Rules. My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule admin/add-category$ adm_add_category.php [NC]
RewriteRule admin/categories-management$ adm_categories_management.php [NC]
RewriteRule admin/user-settings/(.*)$ adm_user_settings.php?update=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule admin/website-settings/(.*)$ adm_website_settings.php?update=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule admin/users-management$ adm_users_management.php [NC]
RewriteRule admin/websites-management$ adm_websites_management.php [NC]

RewriteRule settings/profile$ changesettings.php [NC]
RewriteRule settings/websites$ my_websites.php [NC]
RewriteRule settings/password$ changepassword.php [NC]
RewriteRule settings/logout$ logout.php [NC]

RewriteRule pages/index$ index.php [NC]
RewriteRule pages/access$ access.php [NC]
RewriteRule pages/submit-url$ submit_url.php [NC]
RewriteRule pages/online-users$ online_users.php [NC]
RewriteRule pages/register$ register.php [NC]
RewriteRule pages/websites$ websites_list.php [NC]
RewriteRule pages/websites/(.*)$ websites_list.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule pages/contact$ contact.php [NC]

RewriteRule search/(.*)$ search.php?term=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule category/(.*)$ category.php?name=$1 [NC]    

RewriteRule profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule website/(.*)$ website.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

---

All of the rewrites except for the following are working:

```
RewriteRule search/(.*)$ search.php?term=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule category/(.*)$ category.php?name=$1 [NC]    

RewriteRule profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule website/(.*)$ website.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

When trying to load a specific profile, such as /profile/exampleguy, a 404 error is shown. Does anyone know what would cause this?

The 404 looks like:

```
The requested URL /profile/exampleguy was not found on this server. 

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Let me know if you need more information, i really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `L` flag in each rule to make it `[NC,L]` and then add:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

at top of `.htaccess`

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. Please consider marking it as "accepted" whenever SO lets you do so.

Comment: `L` flag marks each rule as Last so that Apache doesn't process rest of of the rules in current pass. Having `MultiViews` enabled contradicts with mod_rewrite since Apache attempts to rewrite on its own when `MultiViews` is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried working in some rewrite conditions to redirect to a default page?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  //Rewrites if the directory doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  //Rewrites if the file doesn't exist

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]  // Change this to suit your needs
```

Also, I would surmise you are getting the 404 because directories like /profile/ actually exists, but not an "exampleguy" and if there isn't another .htaccess in those directories to catch the issue then the server will try to find the page (and fail....)